# General fallback for Guice unable to satisfy Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a bit of an exotic use case: I want to "merge" two injection frameworks (Eclipse E4 DI and Guice).

Specifically, I would like to hook into Guice in a way so that I can provide a fallback for the case when Guice does not find a binding.

So:

- If Guice does find a binding to provide for Key K, Guice shall create an instance and inject
- **Else, Guice shall call my handler so it can check if it could provide an instance for Key K and if so, I provide an instance to be injected**
- Else, Guice shall throw an Injection error

(The first and third bullet is how Guice behaved today. So, what I would like is the second, bold bullet).

Is something like this possible in Guice?

I have found information about [Custom Injection with TypeListeners](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections), but this does not seem to fit exactly to my case, because this is called *before* Guice tries to inject and also, I don't want additional conditions or annotations on my elements to be injected...

Comment: I do not think that is possible simply because Guice does not provide a point to hook into the creation of that. What you want sounds like a delegate and in theory you could wrap an injector into a DelegateInjector but that would not work for any eagerly created beans anyway. I think your best bet is to create a module that contains the E4 DI and binds all those beans into guice as instances. That however is not really a fallback but a replacement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223032/how-to-delegate-creation-of-some-classes-from-guice-injector-to-another-factory

Comment: This can be achieved in CDI with Extensions or with HK2 with a JIT InjectionResolver (https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b35/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/JustInTimeInjectionResolver.html).  This is mainly how the hk2-guice bridge works